# Is it possible to directly access the div of a view in the OpenLaszlo DHTML runtime?

Tags: dhtml, openlaszlo

Is there a public API for accessing the HTML div object of an OpenLaszlo view in the DHTML runtime? There doesn't seem to be an example for that in the OpenLaszlo documentation, but technically it should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the DHTML runtime was created, the OpenLaszlo team decided to hide the implementation details of the HTML div structure from the developer using LZX. While it's not recommended to directly access the underlying object structure of views, there are situations where you have to do it - but it might break your application with future updates of the platform.

Take the following simple example application:

```
<canvas debug="false">

  <view name="v1" x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" bgcolor="red">
  </view>

</canvas>
```

If you compile the application using the query string

> lzoptions=proxied(true)%2Cruntime(dhtml)&target=html

you will just get the application without the developer console. Now, when you inspect the page structure, you will see the following div structure:

```
<body>
  <div id="appcontainer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px none; overflow: hidden; text-align: left; ">
    <div class="lzappoverflow" style="width: 1905px; height: 429px; ">
      <div class="lzcanvascontextdiv" id="lzcanvascontextdiv">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="lzcanvasdiv">
        <!-- visual part of view instance with id="v1" -->
        <div class="lzdiv" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); height: 100px; width: 100px; left: 10px; top: 10px; z-index: 2; "></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've removed the CSS information and added the comment to mark the div representing the view with id=v1. You don't see any div with the id value 'v1', since the view instances are instantiated as JavaScript objects storing a reference to the visual presentation. You can access the div by calling

> v1.getDisplayObject()

which will return

```
<div class=​"lzdiv" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(255, 0, 0)​;​ height:​ 100px;​ width:​ 100px;​ left:​ 10px;​ top:​ 10px;​ z-index:​ 2;​ ">​</div>​
```

The object hierarchy of a view is *view->sprite->__LZdiv* property. That means, for each view OpenLaszlo instantiates a runtime specific sprite object, which in turn generates the corresponding div for the DHTML runtime.

> v1.sprite.__LZdiv.style.backgroundColor
>   "rgb(255, 0, 0)"

Here are the links to the implementations of the [LzView](http://svn.openlaszlo.org/openlaszlo/trunk/WEB-INF/lps/lfc/views/LaszloView.lzs) and [LzSprite](http://svn.openlaszlo.org/openlaszlo/trunk/WEB-INF/lps/lfc/kernel/dhtml/lzsprite/LzSprite.js) class, if you are interested to learn about the internals:

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just wonder why Laszlo never created an API to make integration of JavaScript/CSS with OpenLaszlo apps easier. Especially now, that Flash is not as attractive any more.

Comment: OpenLaszlo used to only support compiling to Flash before version 4.x was released. Unfortunately, when they added HTML5/DHTML mode to it they kept the model the same as the Flash model, so even though it technically outputs a HTML5+JavaScript application, the OpenLaszlo platform gives you the same restrictions as the Flash platform gives you. There has not been an official release of OpenLaszlo for nearly two years, long before Apple removed Flash from iPad and Adobe dropped Flash from Android 4.1, etc., in the days when Flash was "king" and HTML5 was something fairly new.